# Tricks to prevent specific selector to emit value when new action dispatched?

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store

In a same component, I have following code:

```
this.store.select(state => state.someProperty)).pipe(
        takeUntil(this.destroy$),
        // distinctUntilChanged((prev, curr) => JSON.stringify(prev) === JSON.stringify(curr))
      ).subscribe(val => {
        dosomething()
      })
```

And in the same component, I have store action to fire a new value.

```
this.store.dispatch(
            someAction({
              payload: {
                value
              }
            }));
```

I don't want the subscription above to emit value if the below action fires, I know it is not a common requirement nor a built-in support nor a correct pattern that prevent specific store selector to emit values, but I got this requirement from a specific situation.

I have tried to fire a specific token before I dispatch that action, e.g.

```
this.storeToken$.next('Hey, some one please don't emit following action')
this.store.dispatch(
            someAction({
              payload: {
                value
              }
            }));
```

And trying some rxjs tricks when subscribing the selector:

```
race(this.store.select(state => state.someProperty).pipe(
      delay(100)), this.storeToken$)
```

I want to filter the token away, but it never works. The store selector always win the race,

May I ask if anyone have idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can just take the first value with the `take` operator.
If  you need to be more specific, use one of the `distinct`  operators or `filter`.

```
this.store.select(state => state.someProperty).pipe(take(1))
```

Comment: Sorry, I need to prevent the emit for that specific dispatch, but not all action in other components.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing all the requirements then